# python video streaming display packets

Tags: python, sockets, video-streaming

I am working on a Networks course project, in which I have to create a video streaming server. I found [this link](https://gist.github.com/marvin/4318413) for a simple python client/server socket binary stream that seems quite useful. I am able to send video files as packets over the network, but the receiving side is saving the incoming packets as a file. I would like to display the incoming packets as a video stream (preferably on a web browser using HTML), instead of writing to a file. Please suggest some possible method of doing this. Thanks.

As I am doing a project, I would like to create a streaming server from scratch rather than use existing implementations like Flumotion.

Here's the code for the sending and receiving sides:

Sending side:

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9876
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZE = 4096
videofile = "./test2.mp4"

bytes = open(videofile).read()

print len(bytes)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

client.send(bytes)

client.close()
```

Receiving side:

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 9876
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZE = 4096

serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serv.bind(ADDR)
serv.listen(5)

print 'listening ...'

while True:
    conn, addr = serv.accept()
    print 'client connected ... ', addr
    myfile = open('testfile.mov', 'w')

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
        if not data: break
        myfile.write(data)
        print 'writing file ....'

    myfile.close()
    print 'finished writing file'
    conn.close()
    print 'client disconnected'
```

Comment: In this example the client is sending side. It uploads file to server. The server saves that TCP stream to its file. However, you may want something different. If you wish to use a browser to view that video the server must send video using some streaming protocol.